# Corrupted file while manipulating files

Tags: java, file, io

Hello i am trying to manipulate a file(copying temp to orig.) but it seems that there is a problem (access is denied) whenever i try to open transaction_sales.dat file for the second time. What should I do? :(((

```
public static void writeFile() {
        Path file = null;
        Path file2 = null; 
        OutputStream output = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String[] strReaderAssign = new String[10000];   // for reading files
        String strReader = null;
        int strike = 0; // counter

        try {   // UNFINISHED
            file = Paths.get("transaction_sales.dat");
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
            input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file));
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            if(reader.readLine() == null) { // if file is empty
                writer.write(strHolder, 0, strHolder.length()); // writes to file
                writer.close(); // closes file
                reader.close(); // closes read file
            }

            else {  // write to temporary file
                file = Paths.get("transaction_sales.dat");
                file2 = Paths.get("transaction_sales_temp.dat");    // temporary file
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file2));
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
                writer.write((strHolder), 0, strHolder.length());   // writes to temp file

                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    writer.newLine();   // writes new line to file 10x
                }
                writer.close(); // closes file

                    try {
                        file = Paths.get("transaction_sales.dat");  // re-reads updated data in a file
                        input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file));
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                            while((strReader = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                strReaderAssign[strike] = strReader;    // assigns to array
                                strike++;   // increment
                            }
                        strike = 0; // resets value
                        reader.close(); // closes file
                        // appends file
                        output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file2, APPEND));
                        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
                        for(int j = 0; (strReaderAssign[j] != null); j++) {
                            writer.write(strReaderAssign[j]);
                            writer.newLine();
                        }
                        // resets value 
                        for(int j = 0; j < strReaderAssign.length; j++) {
                            strReaderAssign[j] = null;  
                        }
                        writer.close(); // closes file

                        file = Paths.get("transaction_sales.dat");
                        file2 = Paths.get("transaction_sales_temp.dat");
                        Files.copy(file2, file, REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        Files.delete(file);

                    }
                    catch(IOException d) {
                        System.out.println(d.getMessage());
                    }
            }


        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: Am I reading this right: you create this file, and create a BufferedWriter for it, and them *immediately* create a BufferedReader for it?

Comment: Please identify which of the various times this program tries to open a file is failing.